# Multitenant app issue accessing graph api

Tags: .net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I have a multitenant application js client with masal and Web Api all is working good. User can log in and use the Api.

I'm trying to read the ad groups user belongs to with Graph Api.
It works fine for the user on the same tenant where the app has been registered but if I'm using user from different tenant I have 403 (Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.) error, trying to access /users/{userId}/memberOf endpoint.
After I registered applications on azure for client and server I set the appropriate permissions in Api permission section (Application permission) which I thought is the case but it must me missing something else.
Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to aricle below :

[Understand user and admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent)

> For a multi-tenant application, the initial registration for the application lives in the Azure AD tenant used by the developer. When a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions requested by the application. If they consent, then a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant, and sign-in can continue. A delegation is also created in the directory that records the user’s consent to the application.

Your application uses permissions(`/users/{userId}/memberOf`) that require admin consent, if an ordinary user tries to sign in to an application that requests a delegated permission that requires administrator consent, your application receives an error.

In Azure AD V2.0 , you can redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform admin consent endpoint:

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
&scope=
https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read 
https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send
```

See document : [Admin consent on the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent)